# Create a Series of lists of 1...N for N rows

Tags: python-polars

I'm attempting to create `pl.Series` where each element for row n is a list of items 1...n. Using `pl.arange` doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to finagle it into my desired result:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}).select(
    pl.arange(1, pl.col('a')+1)
)
```

It appears `pl.arange` generates a [vertical] Series and cannot be aggregated into lists. I can get around this by using python's range:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

print(df.with_columns([
    pl.col('a').apply(lambda x: list(range(1, x+1))).alias('c')
]))
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ a   ┆ c             │
│ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ [1, 2]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ [1, 2, 3]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ [1, 2, ... 4] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ [1, 2, ... 5] │
└─────┴───────────────┘
```

But this probably isn't nearly as performant.

Comment: "...finagle it"; that's a +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but we can do this with `groupby_rolling`

```py
N = 6
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            'a': range(1,N)
        }
    )
    .with_row_count(offset=1)
    .groupby_rolling("a",period=f"{N}i").agg(pl.col("row_nr"))
)
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ a   ┆ row_nr        │
│ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ list[u32]     │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ [1, 2]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ [1, 2, 3]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ [1, 2, ... 4] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ [1, 2, ... 5] │
└─────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pl.arange()` with `.list().over()`

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .with_column(
...       pl.arange(1, pl.col("a") + 1)
...       .list()
...       .over(pl.col("a"))
...       .alias("c"))
... )
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ a   | c             │
│ --- | ---           │
│ i64 | list[i64]     │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   | [1]           │
├─────┼───────────────┤
│ 2   | [1, 2]        │
├─────┼───────────────┤
│ 3   | [1, 2, 3]     │
├─────┼───────────────┤
│ 4   | [1, 2, ... 4] │
├─────┼───────────────┤
│ 5   | [1, 2, ... 5] │
└─//──┴─//────────────┘
```